# unit test fails to link because of undefined reference to a function in c project

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, cmake, boost

I am writing a simple unit test using boost unit test frame work. But the test file fails to compile as it is unable to find reference to a function

Compilation error

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/MyTest.dir/test_main.cpp.o: in function `test_add::test_method()':
test_main.cpp:(.text+0x1dedb): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test_main.cpp:(.text+0x1e004): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/MyTest.dir/build.make:105: tests/MyTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:190: tests/CMakeFiles/MyTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
```

If I comment out the `CMakeLists.txt` file for the unit test then the executable for `main.c` compiles and runs fine.

Here is tree structure of the project

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── my_functions.h
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── main.c
│   └── my_functions.c
└── tests
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── test_main.cpp
```

my_functions.h

```
#ifndef MY_FUNCTIONS_H
#define MY_FUNCTIONS_H

int add(int a, int b);

#endif // MY_FUNCTIONS_H
```

my_functions.c

```
#include "my_functions.h"

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "my_functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    printf("Sum of 3 and 4 is %d\n", add(3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

test_main.cpp

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include "../include/my_functions.h"

// dummy unit test
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_dummy) {
    BOOST_CHECK(true);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_add) {
    BOOST_CHECK(add(2, 3) == 5);
    BOOST_CHECK(add(0, 0) == 0);
}
```

CMakeLists.txt in the root directory

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyProject VERSION 1.0)

# Set C standard
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

# Include directories
include_directories(include)

# Create a library target for your functions
add_library(my_functions_lib src/my_functions.c)

# Add subdirectories
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

CMakeLists.txt in src

```
# Add executable
add_executable(MyProject main.c)

# Link the library with your executable
target_link_libraries(MyProject my_functions_lib)
```

CMakeLists.txt in tests

```
# Find Boost
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)

# Add test executable
add_executable(MyTest test_main.cpp)

# Link Boost libraries and your function library to the test executable
target_link_libraries(MyTest
    Boost::unit_test_framework
    my_functions_lib
)

# Include directories
target_include_directories(MyTest PRIVATE ../include)
```

I am able to run the `main` function if i comment out the unit test part. Also If I write a dummy unit test with out any reference to the `add` function.

How to properly reference the `add` function in the test_main.cpp ?

Thanks

Comment: Rename "my_functions.c" => "my_functions.cpp" or learn about `extern "C"`.

Comment: You should say you're code fails to link (it does compile). Also is there a reason for you to compile both "C" and "C++" files? Why don't you make everything "C++"?

Comment: Thanks @n.m.couldbeanAI. I am new to C and did not knew this. I tried both of your suggestions individually and both seems to be working.

Comment: boost is really C++ so. By making the extension cpp you tell the compiler to compile your code as C++ to. That works because C++ is (mostly) backward compatible with C++, but actual code written as C++ code will differ a lot from "C". So be aware to make the correct choice. If your "C" code really needs to be "C", use the `extern "C"` approach.